Next-Approute-issue with routegroup after deployment to linux server
We implemetend routegroup in our nextjs project, as shown below there is group created "(base)" and we have "/home" inside this folder, this functionality works well in local windows machine but
when we deploy the same codebase in linux server we started getting this error,
we did provide the permission to client folder after analysing further we found out that
below path with "(base)" is not resolved as linux system is returing the below error
Path error in linux
*-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' at .next/static/chunks/app/%5Blocale%5D/(base) *
When we try to acces teh page url we got error as below
_next/static/chunks/app/%5Blocale%5D/(base)/layout.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
Folder structure
enter image description here
Can someone help us to resolve this issue
we provided the permision after further analysis we found out that linux system not able to parse the path generated from routegroup
